# VBA MS Access can not find Lib Function

Tags: .net, ms-access, vba

This question uses some older tech so please bear with me,  We are trying to patch an old solution until the new one gets deployed in a couple months.  As a result this is really important and I will add a bounty as soon as possible for this problem.

### BACKGROUND

I have a ms access adp project that uses sql server 2005 on Windows SBS 2003 as its back end.  In this project we use some custom API's to connect to some accounting software.  This project has been working for many years.

I declare the custom api dll in the following way:

```
Public Declare Function wSDBOpenDatabase Lib "Sage_SA_dblyr.dll" (ByRef pDBLinkNo As Integer, ByVal wFlags As Integer, ByVal pszAppID As String, ByVal pszUserID As String, ByVal pSZPWD As String, ByVal szHost As String, ByVal szCompId As String, ByVal szPort As String) As Integer
```

As i understand from [THIS MSDN ARTICLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716201%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) the program will look for the dll in the following locations in this order:

1. Directory containing the .exe file
2. Current directory
3. Windows system directory (often but not necessarily \Windows\System)
4. Windows directory (not necessarily \Windows)
5. Path environment variable

So I copied the dll files in to the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12 directory and the program finds the dlls and the functions work.

The company that creates the dlls in use here have updated their files (which happens yearly) so I just copy the new dlls into the above mentioned directory.  In previous years this was all that was required and it all worked.

### PROBLEM

After copying the new dlls from this years update into the same directory, the program is throwing a VBA error **#53 File not found: Sage_SA_dblyr.dll**
This problem does not appear on the development machine, only on machines where the adp project gets packaged and deployed to.

However the development machine will through the same error if I try to explicitly set the file location of the dll, instead of just using the dll name in the function's lib declare statement.

I tried to explicitly set the location of the dll in the following way to solve the deployment machine's issue:

```
Public Declare Function wSDBOpenDatabase Lib "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\Sage_SA_dblyr.dll" (ByRef pDBLinkNo As Integer, ByVal wFlags As Integer, ByVal pszAppID As String, ByVal pszUserID As String, ByVal pSZPWD As String, ByVal szHost As String, ByVal szCompId As String, ByVal szPort As String) As Integer
```

But I get the same error, and I have tried using different locations as well.  I also copied the dll's into any folder I can imagine it would look,  Including the system root folders of windows\system32 and windows\syswow64 depending on 32 vs 64 bit machines.

NOTE: Theses dll do not require registration

### QUESTION

Can someone help me either explicitly set the file location for the dll declaration or figure out why the adp project cant find the new version of these dlls.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you had a look in the registry for that file (both on the dev machine and on the targets? Perhaps the new version of that dll uses sage services and they are installed and registered on the dev-machine but not (or false/older...) on the dev-machine. BTW: If you get external dlls - aren't they supported?

Comment: Could it be a 32-bit vs. 64-bit issue?

Comment: @Johanness - thanks, the dev machine gets the error if I specify a filepath in the declaration instead of just using the filename alone.  So I don't think its a services issue.

Comment: @SO - could be but he problem appears on 32 and 64 bit end user machines.  I am still looking into this though.

Comment: @Johanness And yes, I have a support ticket in as well - unfortunately this is time sensitive so I am looking for any help I can get.

Comment: Trusted locations issue? Sometimes windows updates break stuff in Office. Access Version ?

Comment: have you tried to register the dll? try register using regsvr32 dllname.dll make sure its 32bit otherwise use 64bit command

Comment: Since this is x32, then that path name looks wrong. Should it not be c:\Program Files (x86) etc. Also, you CAN place the .dll in the SAME dir as the adp, but just make sure you do a chDir to the current db before you attempt to run that code. I would also consider using loadlib to “load” the library based on the assumption that the .dll is in the same dir as the adp application. As noted, this lib code is NOT a COM object and thus no regsvr32 is required.

Comment: Are you using 32 bit or 64 bit Access. The syntax for an API call is a little different in 64 bit. For example, the Declare statement needs to include a PtrSafe.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal thanks - i confirmed that this is 32 bit and I will try what you suggest and get back to you.

Comment: In cases where it's not a 64/32 problem, it is gonna be a permissions or security zone problem

Comment: Have you considered deploying both the application and the dll to a subfolder in the user's %localappdata% folder? This is usually a safe place even in a Citrix environment.